# Grails filterPane plugin to fit page layout

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I would like to have the filterPane to be inserted in my own div in order to fit my page layout. Basically I want to get rid of the default pop-up behavior and harmonize filterPane with the other elements of the application.

this is my gsp

```
<div class="filter">

            <p>
              <filterpane:isFiltered>
                  <filterpane:currentCriteria  domainBean="demoracer.Pilot" />
              </filterpane:isFiltered>
            </p>

<g:formRemote method="post" name="form_search" url="${[action:'list']}" update="listContainer" >

    <filterpane:filterPane customForm="true" formName="form_search" domainBean="demoracer.Pilot"  
filterProperties="name," id="filterpaneContainer"  />

  <g:actionSubmit value="Apply Filter From Outside Filter Pane" action="list" />

</g:formRemote>

          </div>
```

but the pane do not show up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't seems possible since the html is statically created by the taglib

```
   def output = """\
<div id="${containerId}"
    class="filterPane ${containerClass ?: ''}"
    style="display:none;${containerStyle}">
<h2>${title}</h2>
${openFormTag}
<input type="hidden" name="filterProperties" value="${propsStr}" />
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="filterTable">
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the filterpane generates its own div, can't you just use the div it generates and restyle it to fit your layout?  You can specify the id, class, and style attributes of the container div it generates.  That should be more than enough to restyle it any way you'd like.